# Lagrange-mean like inequality

Tags: analysis

I had this problem on an assignment a while ago, but I don't quite understand the formulation of the problem nor the purpose:

> Let $f : [a,b]→\mathbb{R}$ be a function that admits a derivative (not necessarily
> finite!) at any point of $[a,b]$. Prove that there exists $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that: $|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}|\leq |f'(x_0)|$

The original solution was a bit convoluted, and was by constructing some nested intervals, but can't we just say that if the derivative is infinite at some point then we're done, otherwise $f$ is differentiable and we're done by Lagrange's mean theorem? What's wrong with this?

Comment: first state the mean value theorem

Comment: @Andrew For a function continuous in $[a,b]$ differentiabe in $(a,b)$, there exists $x \in (a,b)$ such that: $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(x)$

Comment: those hypotheses are not satisfied here

Comment: Well if the derivative is finite for each $x\in [a,b]$, they're satisfied no?

Comment: hmm, yes i think you are right then, in that case

Comment: @ZNatox, moderators have deleted my answer because in their opinion I have not answered to your question. If you are interested in a proof that there exist $x_1,x_2\in[a,b]$ such that $f’(x_1)\leqslant\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\leqslant f’(x_2)$, you should write it in your question and so perhaps moderators will undelete my answer and you will be able to see my proof.